# Programmatically change database for heroku dataclips

Tags: heroku, heroku-postgres

We just upgraded our Heroku postgres database using the [follower changeover](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/upgrading-heroku-postgres-databases#upgrade-with-follower-changeovers) method.  We have over 50 dataclips attached to the old database, and now we need to move them over to the new database.  However, doing them one by one will take a lot of time.

Is there a programatic way to update the database a dataclip is attached to, perhaps with the CLI tools?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

At least once the old database has been deprovisioned, you can now (as of March 2016) reattach them to another database:

Go to https://dataclips.heroku.com/clips/recoverable. It will display your old database and a set of 'orphaned' dataclips and you can choose to transfer them to another database (in my case the promoted follower from the changeover).

Note that this only affects the dataclips that *you* created, it does *not* affect the dataclips one of your team members created and that you only had access to. So they will have to go through this process as well.

Official devcenter article: https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/dataclips#dataclip-recovery

Comment: I should add that I just did that, and it didn't recover *all* of my dataclips. ;) I'm not sure what the cause of that is, might have just been a hiccup or a mistake on my end. I'm in contact with the Heroku support.

Comment: Update: seems like the recovery process works, but it's *per user* based on who originally created a data clip, so each team member has to go through the process and recover their own data clips.

Answer (score 4):

Thanks to Heroku CSRF measures, programmatically updating data clips is much more difficult than you might expect.  You'll need to suck it up and start clicking buttons by hand, or beg their support team to do it for you, which is just as difficult.

---

There is no official support for programmatically moving the dataclips.  That being said, you can script it out against their HTTP API.

The base URL is `https://dataclips.heroku.com/api/v1/`. There are three relevant endpoints:

- clips `/clips`
- resources (databases) `/heroku_resources`
- move clip `/clips/:slug/move`

Find the slug of the clip you want to move, find the resource id of the new database, and make a post to the move clip endpoint:

```
POST /api/v1/clips/fjhwieufysdufnjqqueyuiewsr/move
Content-Type: application/json

{"heroku_resource_id":"resource123456789@heroku.com"}
```

Comment: No CSRF issue when you're on the same page ! I guess with your knowledge of it and [the batch hack I've found](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64388113/6320039) it could be possible to have something efficient ?

Answer (score 2):

I had over 300 dataclips to move. I used the following technique to update them all (essentially reverse engineering the dataclips API).

1. Open Chrome with Web Developer tools, Network tab.
2. Log into Heroku Dataclips
3. Observe the network call which returns all the dataclips, in JSON (`https://dataclips.heroku.com/api/v1/clips`). Take this response and extract out all dataclip slugs.
4. Update the database for one dataclip. Observe the network call which does this (`https://dataclips.heroku.com/api/v1/clips/:slug/move`). Right click, Copy as cURL. This is the easiest way to get all the correct parameters, since the API uses cookies for authentication.
5. Write a script that loops through each dataclip slug, and shells out to curl. In Ruby, this looks like:

   ```
   slugs = <paste ids here>.split("\n")
   slugs.each do |slug|
     command = %Q(curl -v 'https://dataclips.heroku.com/api/v1/clips/#{slug}/move' -H 'Cookie: ...' --data '{"heroku_resource_id":"resource1234567@heroku.com"}')
     puts command
     system(command)
   end
   ```

Comment: Turns out they use Graphql now (2022) and the POST request is a bit more complex to replicate.

Answer (score 1):

You can contact Heroku support, and they will bulk transfer the dataclips to your new database for you.

Answer (score 0):

## Batch working on dataclips

I've finally found a solution to work on my Dataclips as a batch using the javascript console and some scraping technique. I needed it to retrieve every dataclips. But it guess It can be updated as such:

```js
// Go to the dataclip listing (https://data.heroku.com/dataclips).
// Then execute this script in your console.
// Be careful, this will focus a new window every 4 seconds, preventing
// you from working 4 seconds times the number of dataclips you have.

// Retrieve urls and titles
let dataclips = Array.
    from(document.querySelectorAll('.rt-td:first-child a')).
    map(el => ({ url: el.href, title: el.innerText }))


/**
 * Allows waiting for a given timeout before execution.
 * @param {number} seconds
 */
const timeout = function(seconds) {
    return new Promise(resolve => {
        setTimeout(() => {
            resolve()
        }, seconds);
    })
}

/**
 * Here are all the changes you want to apply to every single
 * dataclip.
 * @param {object} window
 */
const applyChanges = function(window) {
}

// With a fast connection, 4 seconds is OK. Dial it down if you
// have errors.
const expectedLoadTime = 4000 // ms

// This is the main loop, windows are opened one by one to ensure focus and a
// correct loading time.
for (const dataclip of dataclips) {
    // This opens another window from the script, having access to its DOM.
    // See https://github.com/buonomo/kazoo for a funnier example usage!
    // And don't be shy to star and share :D
    const externWindow = window.open(dataclip.url)
    // A hack to wait for loading, this could be improved for sure.
    await timeout(expectedLoadTime)
    
  applyChanges(externWindow)
  
    externWindow.close()
}
```

You'd still have to implement `applyChanges` yourself which I conceed is a bit tedious and I don't have time to do it know (if one does, please share!). But at least it can be done on all of your dataclips in a single function.

For an example usage of this script, you can take a look at [the gist I made to scrape every dataclips and related errors](https://gist.github.com/BuonOmo/c6c5e5b1859c4988083a85ff95f511e8).